# why is dplyr arrange not ordering my dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame

```
> S
Source: local data frame [1,991 x 3]
Groups: exp

   exp year commval
1  alb 1995     186
2  alb 1997     232
3  alb 1998     244
4  alb 2000     251
5  alb 1996     275
6  alb 1999     290
7  alb 2001     313
8  alb 2002     358
9  alb 2003     471
10 alb 2004     608
.. ...  ...     ...
```

I want to filter on year == 1995 and than reorder on commval:

```
> S %>% filter(year == 1995) %>% arrange(commval)
Source: local data frame [130 x 3]
Groups: exp

   exp year commval
1  alb 1995     186
2  are 1995   20266
3  arg 1995   21178
4  arm 1995      60
5  aus 1995   49855
6  aut 1995   50115
7  aze 1995     102
8  bel 1995  150850
9  ben 1995     182
10 bfa 1995     231
.. ...  ...     ...
```

As you can see the result is not sorted on commval but on exp. What am I doing wrong here?

Some more info on conflicts() and sessionInfo():

```
> conflicts()
[1] "filter"    "body<-"    "intersect" "kronecker" "setdiff"   "setequal"  "union"    

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.3.0.2  igraph_0.7.1   reshape2_1.4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] assertthat_0.1  DBI_0.3.1       lazyeval_0.1.10 magrittr_1.5    parallel_3.1.2  plyr_1.8.1     
[7] Rcpp_0.11.3     stringr_0.6.2   tools_3.1.2
```

Comment: What about `S %>% filter(year==1995) %>% dplyr::arrange(commval)`? If you run `conflicts()` do you see `arrange()` listed? Did you load another package that defines `arrange()` or have you defined a same-named function? It would be nicer to have a fully [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Maybe share your `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: tried S %>% dplyr::filter(year == 1995) %>% dplyr::arrange(commval), did not solve my problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the output

```
Source: local data frame [1,991 x 3]
Groups: exp
```

We can see that your data is grouped by `exp`. This means that when you arrange, you will be arranging with the groups. If that's not what you want, do

```
S %>% filter(year == 1995) %>% ungroup() %>% arrange(commval)
```

to ungroup the data before arranging

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour of `arrange` on grouped data has changed a few times across different versions of dplyr. As of release 0.7 (September 2017), by default `arrange` will *not* sort by groups, thus

```
data %>% group_by(grp) %>% arrange(x)
```

will be sorted by `x`, without regard for `grp` (which actually makes the original question moot).

To change this, specify `.by_group=TRUE` in the call to `arrange`:

```
data %>% group_by(grp) %>% arrange(x, .by_group=TRUE)
```

This will be sorted by `grp`, and then by `x` within each `grp`.